# What is SOFEA?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, sofea

I've came across this new acronym, SOFEA, apparently a new programming paradigm for web applications.

Still didn't manage to make sense of it - if someone volunteers to make it clearer for me I'll be very thankful.

Comment: The acronym stands for Service-Oriented Front-End Architecture.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SOFEA is an abbreviation for Service Oriented Front End Applications/Architecture, it refers to a web application architecture where all of the UI functionality is provided by javascript or flash-based logic.  It doesn't interact with the web server per se to provide application level access to data, but rather interacts with web services through AJAX.  Essentially, you provide all of the UI logic in a single (or few) web pages. These pages work with web services to access and update data.

[Reference](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/tsa-working-group-site) at InfoQ

Answer (score 2):

AKA SOUI by the way... (Service Oriented UI) ref: [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/11/soui-death-of-mvc2)

Answer (score 0):

As integration on the response  above, as alternative for the comunication between the two decoupled layer presentation and busines logic you can use different technics and technology as XML or Json using REST & RESTFUL paradigm or even SOAP and last but defenetly not least websocket.