# Taking the good parts of both Spring and php in a common server environment

Tags: php, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jms

What I would propose would probably sound strange, but I have my reasons for it.

For a long time, we've had this Spring based API, which originated as an abstract set of REST services for CRUD functionality. With time however, we started building business and presentation layers on top until we reached a state of a dead end. Do not get me wrong, Spring/Hibernate are great frameworks, and being built on top of the JVM has its definite advantages, including performance over other web technologies, such as PHP. Compared to PHP, it gives us a much deeper way of controlling aspects such as transactioning, multithreading, dealing with byte data, control over native C++ applications, using JNI, etc.

Where the stack clearly hits a hard wall, is where the requirements get changed most often, namely the business and presentation layers. Turning the applciation into a modern, user-centered social applciation, we've experienced the toughest challenge in out careers. Java EE presentation technologies are tough to work with. Also, changing the business requirements became a tremendously long cycling because of the traditional hurdles in building testing and deploying massive Java applications.

It also felt like for a large part, we are trying to reinvent the wheel. In the PHP world, so many projects exist already, which give you a complete management system, agnostic to any kind of backend system (mapping hooks to REST/SOAP endpoints) . Many of them have all these functionalities ready, allow for admin-friendly change of scenarious, and rules, have templating, etc. Plus, being PHP based means absolutely no time wasted in building and deploying. Write the change, test, asert that it works, and switch.

Our idea now is to find a way to move the business and presentation layers in such a kind of front-server PHP-based application, and leave the pure backend stuff to Spring/Hibernate. We have a few concerns though, coming from our relative inexperience with Spring.

1. If we implement the business methods using PHP methods, how do we keep transactional security? I mean if a business method has to make three separate HTTP requests to the JAVA, how can we guarantee that they will all be executed in the same transaction, DB-wise?
2. Is there a way to use proxies or promise objects between both systems? For instance, if the PHP business method needs to call a Spring search method get a collection of objects from the database, and then pass it on to another spring method, this will mean that teh whole collection will have to be sent back and forth. Perhaps, one could store it in a session object on the JAVA side, and simply sent an empty proxy back to the frontend, which the  frontend can bass back to another jav method.
3. A lot of our Spring based functionailities rely on a structure of plugins, using Spring events. How can we make so that our frontend server also gets notified on every ackend event that happens. 
   I have two ideas here: a post-processing-filter that simply makes a POST request to a controller on the frontend server, using some naming convention.
   or ... using some kind of a message queue, such as JMS or RabbitMQ, or why not even something like Reddis, where one can watch data for changes

Anyone who has done that before? Is this a good idea in general? Any suggestions how to resolve the aforementioned issues?

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you asked, but I think it's worth saying that some of the problems you are experiencing with Java are problems that most experienced Java developers faced some day, and most have found some solution. For instance, you can use Arquillian to do a "faster" TDD in Java. And you can use JRebel to do a "code-and-refresh" approach, like in PHP. Modern IDEs also helps in refactoring, something that helps in the "requirements change" scenario.

Granted, the presentation part is still a big problem with Java. I personally don't like JSF, and (to me), most of the other presentation technologies are either non-intuitive or they are cumbersome.

I would say that this is the reason why a lot of Java developers are becoming adopters of HTML5 and Javascript (backbone.js, underscore.js, jquery, ...) for the frontend, with REST in the backend. There's *no* need to have PHP in the middle.

I'm afraid I cannot answer your other questions, but perhaps a good start would be to see if PHP could be run from inside a Java EE container? I know this works for Ruby and Python apps, as JRuby and Jython would take care of the bridge between the two world.

Answer (score 0):

Largely what you are trying to do is what we call: [SOFEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817617/what-is-sofea)

In this case PHP is your frontend and Java is your service layer.

**Concern 1**

Transactions over traditional REST or WS are a PITA.
Either consider aggregating your service calls to do more work so that the whole entire transaction is in one service calls or have Java handle your frontend. Otherwise see *Concern 3* with Finagle.

**Concern 2**

I recommend you stay stateless and do REST or RCP.
It sounds like your concerned with speed which I think you shouldn't worry about till its a problem. However if you do want to do user based caching of objects I would use Redis and its pub/sub feature (or RabbitMQ + memcache).

**Concern 3**

Use RabbitMQ, or Redis, or/and Finagle.

**MY final Opinion**

**I don't think you need PHP particularly if you know Java.**
So much of the web app world today is moving towards Javascript (in the client) I don't see any benefit to using something like PHP serving pages when there are better options like Node.js or just sticking with Java.

And @jpkrohling is right... templating and frotend used to suck in Java but its gotten much better particularly since most of your UI code will be in Javascript anyway.
If you need an example of more modern web stuff in Java have a look at this project: [MWA](https://github.com/jknack/modern-web-app) and also by the same author: [Handlebars in Java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java).

To sum it up my opinion and go back to SOFEA: backend = Java and frontend = Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this before, not sure if it's a good idea, but here are some thoughts on your questions:

1. First of all, in the PHP world, each request (whether it uses keep-alive or not) is run as an isolated process, so this scenario is typically unheard of; it's possible to use persistent database connections, but any non-committed transactions are automatically rolled back when the request is done. Now, this is where my knowledge about Spring is lacking, because I'm not sure whether Java can keep a database connection in the same state between requests as long as the same HTTP connection is used; if so, you can use PHP + cURL to perform three HTTP requests while reusing the network connection.
2. Object (un)marshaling between PHP and Java will probably not work very well; a representation of the collection would have to be made in the form of perhaps a result identifier that can be fetched via REST by PHP and passed back to Java as an opaque string.
3. It should be noted that PHP requests are typically short-lived, which makes it a good candidate for horizontal scaling; long running processes, such as those for Pub/Sub systems, are therefore seen less often. Personally I prefer using the alternative of sending HTTP requests so that the frontend caching can be abstracted away from the Java service.

I'll add more when I think of anything else, do let me know if my answer gives you more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no straightforward way out. You have to **re-write** your backend controller layer which exposes REST calls to PHP. You need to group some fine grained services and make them coarse grained.

A word of advise - you can make things work at the end day with tweaking here and there, introducing a queue or another framework or library etc - but you would have also introduced lot of [Accidental complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity)..
Things can get real nasty in future during maintenance, bug fixes, upgrades etc

If speed of development is a concern, explore other alternative like [Play Framework 1.2.x](http://www.playframework.org/) framework, so that you can re-use your server side code as it is.

Comment: Truth is, I was quite a fan of Play until they introduced v2.0 and thus changed it to the point of irreversibility